# Node.js MySQL mass insert operation fails

Tags: mysql, sql-server, node.js

Below is my code for mass insert into my MYSQL Db

```
connectionPool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
        if(err) {
            winston.log('info', '------- ERROR while getting connection: ' + err.message);
            connection.release();
            return;
        }

        connection.query('INSERT INTO PollOptions (idPollOption, Option, PollId) values ?', [pollOptionsArray], function(err, rows){
            if(err) {
                winston.info('info', '----------------------- ERROR: ' + err);
                connection.release();
                return;
            }
            connection.release();
        });
    });
```

Where the pollOptionsArray is

```
[
  ["POPE1lrKXMy9Q","Adam","POLL4yrFXzkcX"],
  ["POPVy-StXGJcm","Mike","POLL4yrFXzkcX"],["POPNkMSFmGy97","Lucy","POLL4yrFXzkcX"]
]
```

The database table has the following columns

> idPollOption, Option, PollId (all VARCHAR)

It gives me the following error:

> ERROR: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'Option, PollId) values ('POPE1lrKXMy9Q',
>   'Adam', 'POLL4yrFXzkcX'), ('POPVy-StXGJ' at line 1

I even tried to hardcode my sql input like this:

```
var temp = [
        ['123', 'demian@gmail.com', 'POLLVJsBGIjYQ'],
        ['345', 'john@gmail.com', 'POLLVJsBGIjYQ'],
        ['567', 'mark@gmail.com', 'POLLVJsBGIjYQ'],
        ['678', 'pete@gmail.com', 'POLLVJsBGIjYQ']
    ];
```

But it still gives me the same error. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Clearly my SQL syntax is incorrect at the values but what is the remedy?

I even tried to remove the '[]' in the pollOptionsArray and it gives me the same error.

Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

So there was no issue with my syntax. The problem was the column named "Option". 
Apparently "Option" is a reserved keyword in MySQL and since I used it to name my column, it was giving me trouble.